# Are these two regexes functionally equivalent?

Tags: regex

Are the following two regular expressions functionally equivalent?  I ask because I get different results when I interchange them so I guess I know the answer is that they are not equivalent.  However, I don't understand why.

```
(,|$)
```

and

```
[,$]
```

I am basically looking for a comma or the end-of-line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one means a comma or end_of_line

The second means a comma or a dollar sign

Generaly special characters inside a class lose their special meaning.

So, for your question:

> I am basically looking for a comma or the end-of-line.

Use the first one `(,|$)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you put $ into bracket it is considered like the dollar char and not the end of line

you will found more information here : 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

extract :

> Metacharacters Inside Character Classes
>
> Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a
>   character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the
>   caret (^) and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal
>   characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by
>   a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will
>   work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character
>   class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

Answer (score 1):

No. The square brackets will treat the $ as the character, thus removing its status as the end of line marker.